# Display an internal table?

Tags: abap

I have to read some data from a table and display it. The program starts but I don't know how to display any of the data I've selected. I want to put it out as a table.

I honestly don't even know if the following code is correct.

```
REPORT ZT_THIEMANN_TEST.

types : begin of ts_output,
          object_id  type CRMD_ORDERADM_H-object_id,
          created_by type CRMD_ORDERADM_H-created_by,
        end of ts_output,
        tt_output type table of ts_output.

PARAMETERS Mel_Nr TYPE CRMD_ORDERADM_H-Object_ID obligatory.

data gt_output type tt_output.

START-OF-SELECTION.

SELECT cm~object_id cm~created_by
from CRMD_ORDERADM_H as cm
into corresponding fields of table gt_output
where cm~object_id like Mel_Nr.
```

Comment: Hi @Teaman, please google "ALV Grid". As far as I know it's the easiest option to display internal tables.

Comment: @konstantin Please convert your comment into an answer, I don't think you need to add a lot of extra information, just a snippet (for example with `CL_SALV_TABLE`).

Comment: Simply use the **debugger** (add a break point and run the program). PS: in your case, you want a break point after the last line of code (`SELECT`), so you may find it easier to add a dummy statement right after that line.

Answer (score 4):

As Sandra said, you can check if your code/the select works by using the debugger.

You can output data different ways, but the easiest is using the class `CL_SALV_TABLE`. Without adding any additional features (such as a title, toolbar buttons, sorting, hotspots, etc.), the below code is how you can display your data using the oo alv grid.

```
...

DATA: go_alv       TYPE REF TO  cl_salv_table,
      gx_salv_msg  TYPE REF TO  cx_salv_msg.

...

  TRY.
      cl_salv_table=>factory(
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = go_alv
      CHANGING
        t_table = gt_output ).
    CATCH cx_salv_msg INTO gx_salv_msg.
      MESSAGE 'error' TYPE 'E'.
  ENDTRY.

  go_alv->display( ).
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a real one-liner, just use ABAP demo output standard class `cl_demo_output` that can handle any type including internal tables:

```
SELECT *
   FROM scarr
   INTO TABLE @DATA(carriers).

cl_demo_output=>display( carriers ).
```

Comment: Warning: `CL_DEMO_OUTPUT` should only be used in a test program, it [should not be used productively](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/10/cldemooutput-part-1-of-2--usage/) (like other CL_DEMO* classes). For productive used, something like `CL_SALV_TABLE` is a good solution.

Comment: Indeed, but OP didn't state he want to use it in production. We don't known his intention, maybe it is just a test program :) Anyway it is more handful than checking in debugger as was proposed by Legxis

Comment: The (backend) debugger can display the internal table via ALV ;-)